# How to convert nvarchar to decimal in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to convert an nvarchar to decimal in SQL Server?

I need to convert a value like `'38,716.1311'` to 38716.1311.

I have tried using this method but can't successfully convert:

```
DECLARE @TempValue NVARCHAR(100) = '38,716.1311'

SELECT 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), @TempValue)
```

Can anyone suggest the correct query? Thanks in advance

Comment: How about removing the comma

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove comma from your string prior to conversion:

```
Select CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),replace('38,716.1311', ',', ''))
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the comma by using REPLACE like so:

```
Declare @TempValue nvarchar = '38,716.1311'
Select CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), REPLACE(@TempValue, ',', ''))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @TempValue nvarchar(100)
    SET @TempValue = Replace('38,716.1311',',','')
Select cast(@TempValue AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

--we can not convert value Like "38,716.1311" (NVARCHAR) To DECIMAL so first we replace "," with blank "38716.1311" then convert with DECIMAL

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 4):

Your `nvarchar` values are culture-specific. (Having culture-specific decimal and thousand separators)
Hence you could use the `PARSE` method while passing in the proper culture.

```
DECLARE @TempValue NVARCHAR(100) = '38,716.1311'

SELECT PARSE(@TempValue AS DECIMAL(18, 4) USING 'en-US')
```

Answer (score 2):

Its better if the `@TempValue` is `MONEY` so it disregard the comma separated

```
Declare @TempValue MONEY =  '38,716.1311'
Select CAST(@TempValue AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MONEY data type and convert into decimal data type:

```
DECLARE @Col MONEY = '38,716.1311'
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,4),@Col)
```

OR Replace comma and convert into decimal

```
DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(100)  = '38,716.1311'
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,4),REPLACE(@Col,',',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case for example some data like: `version: '1.2.12'`

I want to register like version: 1.212 in Sql

1. Clean the *varchar* ( eliminate dot or commas )
2. Cast to *char* (6 digit) and pad with 0 the empty spaces. (Catch null with coalesce)
3. Cast to *numeric* and divide to 100000
4. Cast to *decimal* (10,4)

Result ->> version 1.212

```
Select 'version'=cast(cast(replace(cast(replace(coalesce([##DATA##],'0'), '.', '') as char(6)),' ','0')as numeric(6))/100000 as decimal (10,4)
```

Maybe there is another solution which is more simple.