# How to convert NVarchar to Decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column as nvarchar(max) whose value is

```
'1.7925e+006'
```

How can this be converted to decimal? I have tried as below

```
declare @pd as nvarchar(max) = '1.7925e+006'
Select convert(decimal(18, 2), @pd)
```

but I get an erorr:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert nvarchar to decimal in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527953/how-to-convert-nvarchar-to-decimal-in-sql)

Comment: Simply `cast('1.7925e+006' as decimal(18,2))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the string represents a floating point number, you'll need to convert the value to a `float` first, and then a `decimal`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,2),CONVERT(float,'1.7925e+006'));
```

Comment: [Working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=57c3dfa6981b94a851a71638451c89b2) for the same.